# Python-How to create spaces between paragraphs?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python programming. When I write my code, it gets really lengthy because I keep using a print('') under paragraphs to create space. So far my programming is with making simple tests for my sister who is a teacher for the upcoming school year. Is there a cleaner, shorter way to make spaces?

Example:

```
print('What is the answer for this question?')
print('')
print('')
print('answer')
```

Comment: use `\r\n` to create newlines.

Comment: '\r\n' actually (we are answering to a beginner so..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New-lines can be added using the escaped character `\n`. For example:

```
print('What is the answer for this question?\n\nanswer')
```

is equivalent in output to your example code.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I really appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! If this answer fulfills your question completely, you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\n` to insert new lines :

```
print('What is the answer for this question?\n\n')
print('answer')
```

If you do not want to print a new line, you can use this :

```
print('What is the answer for this question? ',end='')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I really appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ***\n*** command in a print statement to create an "enter" block I guess.

***Input:***

```
print("This is how you can\nmake breaks!")
```

***Output:***

```
This is how you can
make breaks!
```